# How to find a dynamically added class

Tags: jquery, class, selected

I have this working so far. I checked it in Firebug.
I'm adding a class .selected to the clicked link in the click function. When I click a link the class of #dates a , changes to .selected, when I click another link the class of the previous link is being removed and the clicked link gets a class .selected

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    $('#dates li').click(function()  { 
        $('#dates a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).children().addClass('selected');
    });
```

This code is searching for the id of the list around the link. In most cases the id called, #year1943, #year1953 and so on. I want to use this id to check which year is being clicked/ has the class .selected.

```
    function getSelectedYear() {
        return $("#dates a.selected").parent().attr('id');
    }

    $(function(){

        $('#dates li').click(function()  {
            var selectedYear = getSelectedYear(); 
            if (selectedYear == "year1943"){
                alert('The year is 1943');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

this is my HTML markup

```
<ul id="dates">
    <li id="all"><a href="#all" class="selected">1943-2013</a></li>
    <li id="year1943"><a href="#1943">1943-1953</a></li>
    <li id="year1953"><a href="#1953">1953-1963</a></li>
    <li id="year1963"><a href="#1963">1963-1973</a></li>
    <li id="year1973"><a href="#1973">1973-1983</a></li>
    <li id="year1983"><a href="#1983">1983-1993</a></li>
    <li id="year1993"><a href="#1993">1993-2003</a></li>
    <li id="year2003"><a href="#2003">2003-2013</a></li>
</ul>
```

It seems that when the class .selected is added dynamically, Jquery can't find out which link has the class .selected. It can't notice the changes. I think I need something that re-scans the HTML/CSS markup to check which link has the class .selected.

Comment: is `$'(#dates a').removeClass('selected');` a typo in your question or is it in your actual code aswell? Should be `$('#dates a').removeClass('selected');`

Comment: typo, I retyped the code for this question so didn't use the typo in my actual code. editted my post.

Comment: no probs, thought it was worth checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try make on listener for the `$('#dates li').click` event.

Try:

```
     $('#dates li').click(function () {
            $('#dates a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).children().addClass('selected');
            var selectedYear = getSelectedYear();

            if (selectedYear == "year1943") {
                alert('The year is 1943');
            }
        });


    function getSelectedYear() {
           return $("#dates a.selected").parent().attr('id');
        }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AB22R/1/) (click on the 1943 - 1953)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I totally understang your problem, but if you want to get the ID of the LI element clicked, on click, can't you just use:

```
 $('#dates li').click(function () {
    $('#dates a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).children().addClass('selected');
    var selectedYear = $(this).attr("id");

    if (selectedYear == "year1943") {
        alert('The year is 1943');
    }
});
```

You could also use:

```
$('#dates li').on('click', function() {
    var item = $(this);
    $('#dates a').removeClass('selected');
    item.children().addClass('selected');
    if (item.attr('id') == 'year1943') {
        alert('The year is 1943');
    }
});
```